# "ionic run ios" How to add provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I wish to use Ionic to run my app on my iOs device with livereload enabled. According to the docs this should be easy:

`ionic run ios --device -l`

Of course I have to add provisioning profiles, but how am I supposed to do it?

I have the .mobileprovision and the .p12 of the certificate, but no matter what I do I still get this error when running the command:

`No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “<MyBundleID>” were found`

How am I supposed to add my provisioning profiles? I'm not able to find any info about this in the framework docs.

**Note: I can reploy the project using Xcode, but then I don't get the livereload. Plus I'd prefer doing everything from the CLI.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go into XCode and add those provisioning profiles to your device.

Set those provisioning profiles into the build process and add the profile to the device as well.

Though you may not be using Visual Studio, their explanation on the setup works for all methods of building Ionic apps.

The documentation is [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/), but to tell you what's going on:

1. Make sure you have a developer account to make provisioning profiles.
2. You would sign into Itunes Connect to add your device as a testing device
3. Create an App ID
4. Create a provisioning profile associated to that App ID
5. Download the provisioning file into Xcode
6. Add the provisioning file to your device via Xcode
7. Run ionic run ios --device -l

That should do the trick.

Follow the setup guide by Microsoft starting at create your provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks! That's it: There actually is no way to add the provisioning profiles using Ionic/Cordova. You have to use Xcode for it, and then I assume this process must be repeated whenever you perform a new platform prepare on the project.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it when you recreate the platform, as long as the bundleID stays the same. I clear out the platform all the time to debug and it never became a problem for me. Happy Coding! I love Ionic, it is really good once you get the set up down!